# WebOS Resets LocalStorage On Browser Close?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, html, local-storage, webos

I have an HTML5 webapp wherein I use localStorage to retain some client-side user settings between uses.  I thought I had it all working well, but I recently find that in the WebOS browser the localStorage items are cleared after the browser is completely closed (all cards--not just my page).  It is acting like it is saved to session storage, but that is not the case.  Here is a minimal example that illustrates my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#btnV').click(function() {
                    var x = '';
                    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                        x += localStorage.key(i) + ':' + localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) + '<br/>';
                    }
                    $('#lbl').empty().append(x);
                });
                $('#btnS').click(function() {
                    localStorage.setItem('test', 'blah');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="lbl"></span>
        <input type="button" id="btnS" value="Save" />
        <input type="button" id="btnV" value="View" />
    </body>
</html>
```

When I first load the page and click the "View" button, nothing is shown.  If I click "Save" and then "View" I will see the item as saved.  Refreshing the page and clicking View immediately shows the value is retained across page-reload.  However, if I completely close out the browser and then go back in to the page, "View" will show no values as it did the very first time.  Am I setting localStorage items incorrectly, or is my WebOS browser configured somehow to do this?  I couldn't find anything relevant in the settings.

Thanks...

Comment: Wish I could help, but your code looks fine so I'm guessing it's a WebOS issue (I don't have a palm device on me)

Comment: Does this happen in the emulator?  On device?  What version of the OS?  I've got a couple different devices and versions of the OS in the emulator so I'll try to take a look at this a little later and see where it replicates.

Comment: @GordonWorley @Gordon Worley : Yes, it happens on both the emulator (1.4.5 SDK) and the device (Palm Pre Plus, also 1.4.5). That is all I have to test on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I know, localStorage is not supported in WebOS 1.4.x. I think I remember seeing it listed as a feature that was enabled in WebOS 2.0 (or maybe 2.1), but I cannot find any documentation on the subject, so I could be misremembering.

Assuming you are storing a small amount of data, user settings are usually more appropriately stored in cookies in WebOS using [Mojo.Model.Cookie](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/mojo/classes/mojo-model-cookie.html).

In my own app, I use cookies for user preferences, and store the app data in an HTML5 database database, with my [open-source database class](https://github.com/onecrayon/database-webos) making the HTML5 database access less onerous.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently this is the case... I only find it odd that 1.4.x DOES support it, it just doesn't persist it. Cookies is probably the way I'll go--thanks for the suggestion!